# ASP.NET MVC 1.0: OutputCache, RenderPartial and WriteSubstitution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outputcache, substitution

after digging into this topic and having the requirement, that a single page should be totally cached, except for a

```
Html.RenderPartial("LogOnUserControl");
```

i couldn't find any working solution on this... 
the only "its getting warmer" solution i found was [this one](http://www.klopfenstein.net/lorenz.aspx/render-partial-view-to-string-in-asp-net-mvc) , which unfortunately is not working with a "partial view", which requires the

```
Request.IsAuthenticated
```

attribute ( the fakeContext is losing this info )

Have you heard of any ( other ) solution to cache a whole page except for a single "RenderPartial" call?!

Comment: what exactly is the issue? I'm a little confused.

Comment: Sorry, my problem is that it seems to be impossible to create cached pages, where only some parts are replaced on each request...

Answer (score 1):

Phil Haack has a great article on this that he calls Donut Caching.

Check it out at http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/05/donut-caching-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx

Comment: Checked it already... this does also not work for "RenderPartial" and when i did some tests on it, it seems to me that the "Request" object was also cached ( or at least the last "Request.IsAuthenticated" value )

Comment: ASP.NET's implementation of Donut Caching is very much tied to WebForms, so the MVC pipeline does not support it.  Note that the Html.Substitute() method was removed in MVC 2 Futures because it simply does not work correctly.

Comment: Ok, and there isn't any alternative?!